# Javascript complex REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some definition that come in a similar appearance:
"(adj.) currently holding office (e.g. the ..... president had been defeated)
"
I need to split them in this way:

```
var fullDefinition= " (adj.) currently holding office"
 var definition="currently holding office"
 var word = "....."
 var example = " the " + word + "president had been 
 defeated"
```

The elements  in common for every definition, which I can use as anchors, are
the two brackets " (   )" but not the content inside
the dots " ..... "
the string " (e.g " with the last bracket " )"
I  am newbie, I think I need to use regular expression here, but I don't know how

Comment: Is `(adj.) currently holding office (e.g. the ..... president had been defeated)` the full original formatting?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to accomplish, let me know if this helps: https://regex101.com/r/FeT7Rg/1

Comment: That was the original formatting.Here another example:      (adj.) necessary for (someone) as a duty or responsibility (e.g. it is ..... on all decent people to concentrate on destroying this evil)

Answer (score 0):

This site is great for trying out regular expressions. You can create an account and save the regular expressions.

https://regex101.com/r/I7DFWb/1

Here are some resources to read up on to get an idea of the formats to use.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

RegEx are very cool to use.

Comment: Updated the link as it was broken to the sample I put up there.